# paypal immediate, chained payment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paypal, activemerchant

I have a an application for digital goods which makes use of paypal.
I need to tackle the following scenario:

A buyer  (german paypal account) buys an item, the application itself (german paypal account) should receive a fee and another party  (german paypal account) should receive money.
So I started using adaptive payments (in rails I do use  the active_paypal_adaptive_payment gem), which is working fine.

But as soon as the buyer is located in the us (paypal sandbox account for us seller) I have an unverified checking account. Consequently the payment remains pending until the receiver accepts the payment.

But this is not wanted, since I want to accept only payments which can be processed right away.
So is it possible to use paypal's immediate payment in conjunction with adaptive payment (preferably the active_merchant gem for reils) ?

Best,
Philip

Comment: can you be more specific on what kind of receiver account you are using ? If the receiver has an account - the money movement happens immediately. If the receiver account is not verified (attached to a bank account), there will be restrictions on amount of money the account can receive and how much can be withdrawn from their PayPal account. So not sure what you mean by "receiver accepts the payment". Or did you turn on payment review for your receiver (Seller) account ?

Comment: Hi Praveen, thanks for replying. The primary receiver has an account which is not verified (I dont know how to verify a bank account in the sand box). The secondary receiver (seller's account is configured with the paypal standard settings). What i figured out now, is that it is important that the account is verified. Unless it is not verified the payment will remain pending, which is not wanted. Or at least I would like to make a call in order to get informed about the payment status..

Comment: if you login to developer.paypal.com and click on "Create a preconfigured account" link, you can create a seller account w/ test bank account and credit cards attached - which automatically marks the account as verified.
In chained payment case, the payment for the secondary receiver comes from primary receiver's account behind the scenes - hence the limitations.